# Rails route by alphabet

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm thinking something like this could be accomplished with routing in Rails 3, but how would I handle it in my controller afterwards?

```
match 'items/:letter' => 'items#index', :letter => /[A-Z]/
```

Then I think I would have a param `:letter` in my controller, then I'd need to return the items that have that as the first letter in it's `name`. Does this make sense or am I crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense.

Look for the letter in your query call as follows.

```
@items = Item.where("name LIKE ?%", params[:letter])
```